# How to correctly Open From Path in JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I need to work on my files on a different path in JupyterLab. I tried to use File --> Open from Path. However, whatever I name as my path like C:/.... or E:... or any drive it says that "Could not  find path ...". I was using this option in the last week with no problem, but some issue occurred and I could not figure it out.